# How do I write non-blocking code in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, blocking, eventemitter

I can write non-blocking [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output) in [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)  very easily. It's what the entire library is set up for.

But any computation done is blocking. Any message passing over [event emitters are blocking](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/bc8489580cbc36eca511988ca134326b6ec2e2cc/lib/events.js#L38).

For example, emitting events are resolved immediately and are thus blocking:

```
var e = new process.EventEmitter;
e.on("foo", function() {
    console.log("event");
});
process.nextTick(function() {
    console.log("next tick");
});
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("timeout");
}, 0);
e.emit("foo");

> event
> next tick
> timeout
```

Apart from wrapping calls in `nextTick`, how do I make code non-blocking?

I want to do as little computation per cycle of the event loop as possible, so that I can serve as many clients simultaneously as possible.

How do I write my code in a non-blocking fashion?

And when I have non-blocking code, how do I scale that across multiple processes?

One option is waiting for the WebWorker sub-process API to be finished.

Comment: Firstly, 90% of your 'Question' is not actually a question, it's more of an issue with node's Event Library, this should be brought up either as a feature request or as a possible bug on github, as for your small question I would create a question dedicated to that subject rather then squeezing it in this one.

Comment: @RobertPitt thank you for pointing out that the question was phrased poorly. i have adjusted it. I might also mention it on github.

Comment: That's a little better, thankyou.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript is single-threaded. That means that regardless of events, timeouts, or delaying with nextTick, any computation done will block the whole process.

If you split your processing in steps using `process.nextTick`, like it's done with `setTimeout(fn, 0)` on the client-side to avoid blocking the UI, you could spread your workload over a longer time span, giving some room for other functions to run.

But that's a very innefective solution - the total amount of work is the same, distributed among all cycles (making each request a little slower). In practice, any kind of computation that is expected to take more than a few milliseconds should be offloaded to a different process. To maximize concurrency you should *always return to the event loop as quickly as possible*.

`child_process.fork()` was added to v0.5 a few days ago. It simplifies child process creation and communication - not quite the web workers API, but close, see the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator)
https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/doc/api/child_process.markdown.

Comment: That's exactly what I showed in my snippet. The event handling is blocking. My question is how do I do non blocking message passing to optimise concurrency? I guess calling process.nextTick is the best way.

Comment: @RicardoTomasi using `process.nextTick` is non-blocking as it allows other task to get CPU time. It's basically time splicing one CPU to make it multi threaded.

Comment: Javascript is still single threaded, and your functions will "block" regardless of their placing. The _other tasks_ will also block, you'll be just switching their order. **If** you split your processing in steps, like it's done client-side to avoid blocking the UI, you can spread the same amount of work over a longer time - then you might get a little better concurrency, but in exchange for longer response times. This is not what node.js is about. The benefits of non-blocking code come from not sitting idle waiting for responses, not from avoiding all computations.

Comment: @RicardoTomasi that final comment really sums up my misconceptions. If you can edit the answer to explain my misconception I'll accept it

Comment: @Raynos edited. also added a mention to the new `.fork()` API, you should take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real multi-threading in JavaScript and that's what you need to make the call non-blocking. The only thing I can think of are web-workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers

Comment: Then again, I haven't programmed in JS for several years so I might be wrong.

Comment: callbacks on `process.nextTick` are non-blocking. You can use an event loop to write non blocking code but the event emitters do not make use of the event loop. I don't know how to make use of the event loop.